# Getting an error while executing Query via Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to search rooms that are available **from** start date till **to**  end date.
For example, I want available rooms from 28th of March till 31st of March.
I will search the rooms that are reserved between the provided dates and will return 
all the rooms except for these ones.
I am using sequelize as an ORM.
I have the following query for that, but executing it gives me the following error.

```
    let availableRooms = await Room.findById(id, {
        include: [
                    {
                        model: Reserved,
                        where: {
                                notIn: [
                                    {
                                        from: {
                                            lt: Date.parse('2018-03-31')
                                        }                                       
                                    },
                                    {
                                        to:{
                                            gt: Date.parse('2018-03-28')
                                        }                                       
                                    }
                                ]

                        }                           
                    }
        ]
    });
```

> Error: Invalid value { from: { gt: 1522195200000 } }

**Reserved** is another table with roomID as foreign key.  It contains two more columns.
1) FROM
2) TO
Both columns have DATE type.

Just for reference, the following query works fine.

```
    let availableRooms = await Room.findById(id, {
        include: [
                    {
                        model: Reserved,
                        where: {
                                    from: {
                                        gt: Date.parse('2018-03-28')
                                    },

                                    to:{
                                        lt: Date.parse('2018-03-31')
                                    }                                           
                        }                           
                    }
        ]
    });
```

So can not really  understand why is there there invalid value error?  Is notIn expecting some thing else?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error

> Error: Invalid value { from: { gt: 1522195200000 } }

Coz of values required by `notIn` is `array of values` not the `array of queries` , so above value is not valid for `notIn`
here you are giving the `query` not `values` to the notIn

**E.G. :**

```
notIn: [ 1,2,3 ] // this will work

// Not this
notIn: [
            {
                from: {
                    lt: Date.parse('2018-03-31')
                }                                       
            },
            {
                to:{
                    gt: Date.parse('2018-03-28')
                }                                       
            }
        ]
```

Last query you have posted is fine , that is how you should go.

Comment: But how can I pass the results from nested query in to it? In to the  $notIn function.

Comment: You can't run the subqueries in sequlize you have to get ids first and then use it as I shown in E.G.